# How to diagnose intermittent/triggered network error

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet, 19.04, netplan

**Problem**

Certain actions cause the whole LAN network to fail in resolving domains, the devices can't access anything outside the *LAN* network.

**Example**

When trying top pull a docker image from a self hosted *Gitlab* instance, every device on the network loses internet connection. There are other actions which trigger this effect.

The pull will eventually succeed but at speeds of *<100Kb/s*. Aborting the pull will cause all devices to resume normal operation within minutes.

**Note**

I am still able to ssh into the device while all the devices are unable to access the internet. I can also access any *LAN* samba shares.

The problem seems to only occur when the destination address is the public facing address of the *LAN* network.
Lets say *DNS* records for *example.com* point to *99.99.99.99*, which in this case would be the public facing address. Browsing to *example.com* will be fine from within the *LAN*. Pulling a docker image from *registry.example.com* will break the network.

**Data**

System:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

Ethernet controller:

```
$ lspci |grep Ethernet
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Routes:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp19s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-aa8d8a399367
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b47396405d84
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2bac20a2ccb1
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-c1cedda32d4f
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-db04364eb1ec
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp19s0
```

Network interfaces:

```
$ lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:2f:68:82:81:f6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.0.0-27-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       logical name: enp19s0
       version: 06
       serial: 38:60:77:be:92:40
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.92 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

Followed by a bunch of docker virtual interafeces.

Contents of sole netplan configuration file:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}

# https://netplan.io/reference
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp19s0:
            wakeonlan: true
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.92/24
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 1.1.1.1
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 1.0.0.1
                - 8.8.4.4
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            accept-ra: false
```

**Network**

> [image: https://i.imgur.com/Hics5je.jpg]

- The modem/router combo issued by my ISP is in red and yellow (one physical device).
- The purple device is a wireless access point.
- The blue devices are network switches.

**What I tried**

- Disconnect all but two devices and test.

  - Connect these two devices directly to router/modem combo to rule out switch failure.
- Turn off IPv6 on both Ubuntu devices.

  - Pass `ipv6.disable=1` kernel parameter.
- Update network interface driver.

  - `$ apt install r8168-dkms`
- Set the correct date/timezone.
- Remove nameservers from netplan configuration.
- Looked at Wireshark capture.

  - Not sure what exactly to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I am in no way a network engineer so take this advice lightly.

I fixed my problem by:

1. Creating AAAA records for my domains.
2. Re-enabling IPv6 support on all the devices.
3. Creating IPv6 firewall rules to allow some traffic to the intended host; in other words, create a whitelist.

**Cause**

I am still not certain what caused the sudden DNS failures with IPv6 disabled. My best guess is my ISP changed something on their side (up to and including the modem/router).

**Side notes**

- **Positive:** On a side note, all my services are now fully IPv6 compliant.
- **Negative:** This probably only hides the real problem.